# Flexible entity models with CQRS and EventSourcing

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Quoting from [Rinat Abdullin's article](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/3/23/dddd-cqrs-and-other-enterprise-development-buzz-words.html):

> CQRS and Event Sourcing also simplify implementation of the flexible
>   entity models with various custom fields and properties that are often
>   defined at the run-time and used in layout and drag-n-drop designers
>   by the end-users.

I fail to understand how the runtime custom field definition is possible with event sourcing and cqrs?

Answer (score 1):

Just add IDictionary field to your Commands and Events and then add its contents to Projections when handling Events. Only make sure that the stuff you put in Dictionary is indeed serializable.